# filtering the DataFrame based on condition with Date Column

Tags: pandas

Existing Dataframe :

```
UserId     Activity_date     Status  
A            27-01-2022      initiated        
A            27-01-2022      In_process
A            27-01-2022      Success    
A            28-01-2022      initiated  
A            28-01-2022      Completed
A            30-01-2022      initiated
A            30-01-2022      failed
B            26-01-2022      initiated
B            26-01-2022      Completed
B            26-01-2022      Success
B            27-01-2022      initiated
```

Need to drop those entries where Success or Completed does not appear for the Same Activity Date. as in case of UserId A , Success status appears on the 27-01-2022 and Completed status appears on 28-01-2022 , so the new dataframe should all the rows for the Activity date 27-01-2022 and 28-01-2022

Expected Dataframe :

```
UserId     Activity_date     Status  
A            27-01-2022      initiated        
A            27-01-2022      In_process
A            27-01-2022      Success    
A            28-01-2022      initiated  
A            28-01-2022      Completed
B            26-01-2022      initiated
B            26-01-2022      Completed
B            26-01-2022      Success
```

i approached it with grouping by the UserId and Activity_date and checking the row for 'Success' or 'Completed' status , but stucked with dropping part.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df
    UserId  Activity_date   Status
0   A       27-01-2022  initiated
1   A       27-01-2022  In_process
2   A       27-01-2022  Success
3   A       28-01-2022  initiated
4   A       28-01-2022  Completed
5   A       30-01-2022  initiated
6   A       30-01-2022  failed
7   B       26-01-2022  initiated
8   B       26-01-2022  Completed
9   B       26-01-2022  Success
10  B       27-01-2022  initiated

df1 = df.groupby(['UserId','Activity_date'])['Status'].apply(list).reset_index()

df1
    UserId  Activity_date   Status
0   A       27-01-2022      [initiated, In_process, Success]
1   A       28-01-2022      [initiated, Completed]
2   A       30-01-2022      [initiated, failed]
3   B       26-01-2022      [initiated, Completed, Success]
4   B       27-01-2022      [initiated]

df1.loc[df1['Status'].map(lambda x: ("Success" in x) and ('Completed' in x))].explode('Status')
    UserId  Activity_date   Status
3   B       26-01-2022      initiated
3   B       26-01-2022      Completed
3   B       26-01-2022      Success
```

Comment: status can be either completed or success. if any of this appears for any activity date , then every row w.r.t. to that activity date has to be retained

Comment: what you mean by activity date ? 27-01-2022 is separate activity date than 28-01-2022 or the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).

```
out = df.pivot(index=['UserId','Activity_date'], 
               columns='Status', values='Status')

out = df.set_index(['UserId','Activity_date'])\
    .loc[out[['Completed','Success']].any(axis=1)].reset_index(drop=False)

print(out)

  UserId Activity_date      Status
0      A    27-01-2022   initiated
1      A    27-01-2022  In_process
2      A    27-01-2022     Success
3      A    28-01-2022   initiated
4      A    28-01-2022   Completed
5      B    26-01-2022   initiated
6      B    26-01-2022   Completed
7      B    26-01-2022     Success
```

**Explanation**:

- The pivot gets us columns for each `Status` value per `UserId, Activity_date` pair with either `NaN` or the appropriate value (e.g. `Success`).
- Next, we use [`df.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) on `['Completed','Success']` to check if *at least* one of either columns contains a *non*-NaN value. The result is a `pd.Series` with booleans.
- Finally, we use this series to select the correct rows from the original `df` with `UserId, Activity_date` temporarily set as the index.

Answer (score 0):

df being your database, I suggest this code:

```
df1 = df[df.Status.isin(['Success','Completed'])][['UserId','Activity_date']].drop_duplicates()
df1.merge(df, how='left',on=['UserId','Activity_date'])

df1:

        UserId  Activity_date
2   A   2022-01-27
4   A   2022-01-28
8   B   2022-01-26
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.merge(df1.query("Status=='Success'"),on='UserId',suffixes=['','2'])\
    .merge(df1.query("Status=='Completed'"),on='UserId',suffixes=['','3'])\
    .query('Activity_date==Activity_date2 or Activity_date==Activity_date3')\
    .loc[:,['UserId','Activity_date','Status']]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new column created by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), then call [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test at least one value match, last filter groups by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.assign(new = df['Status'].isin(['Success','Completed']))
          .groupby(['UserId','Activity_date'])['new'].transform('any')]
print (df)
  UserId Activity_date      Status
0      A    27-01-2022   initiated
1      A    27-01-2022  In_process
2      A    27-01-2022     Success
3      A    28-01-2022   initiated
4      A    28-01-2022   Completed
7      B    26-01-2022   initiated
8      B    26-01-2022   Completed
9      B    26-01-2022     Success
```